# Can I install Ubuntu 17.04 on a computer with Windows 10 and Bitlocker enabled without issue?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, 17.04

I've put a lot of effort into the windows side of my computer so I just want to make sure I wont mess it up.

If I have a Windows 10 Computer with UEFI and Bitlocker enabled, can I install Ubuntu the standard way without destroying anything or having to seriously modify things?

Will the standard install work fine?

Comment: I never though I would one day post a Technet link at AU but here it is: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9528.how-to-multiboot-with-bitlocker-tpm-and-a-non-windows-os.aspx

Comment: I saw that article in googling the issue before coming here. Unfortunately, none of the three methods consider if Windows 10 is already installed and encrypted

Comment: Actually method 3 assumes Windows installed first and with Bitlocker (Windows version is irrelevant).

Comment: Method 3 requires the use of easyBCD. My question is asking if I install it in a standard way will it work. This is non-standard.

Comment: Obviously the article refers to MBR/BIOS and that's why EasyBCD is required. The point is it can be done and Bitlocker is a non-issue because it encrypts partition(s) only, not the entire drive. Knowing that, in UEFI mode, you proceed as you normally would - shrink the Windows partition (if required) from Windows - and then install Ubuntu. The Windows boot manager entry at UEFI won't be disturbed. However, you won't be able to dual-boot from Grub, only from the UEFI menu (reason: `os-prober` cannot detect the encrypted Windows partition).